# CVS: list all files added/removed between tags

Tags: cvs

Is there any way to list all the files added/removed to repository between two selected tags? I tried cvs history but it only shows history records since a particular tag was last added to the history file. The command line solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cvs rdiff -s -r <tag1> -r <tag2> <module>`.

There is some example output in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852455/966703).

Comment: Are you sure you meant `rtag`? I think it is used to tag files, like `cvs tag` but requires no prior checkout and work on the repo directly. And it has no -s option...

Comment: `cvs rdiff -s -r <tag1> -r <tag2> <module>` seems to work though. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @alikasundara Yes, I meant `rdiff`. Good catch. I've updated the answer.