# CVS - Show Files Committed Since a Specific Tag

Tags: cvs

Is there a way to display any files that have been changed and committed since a specific tag?

For example, a file index.html is currently at revision 1.5.  Revision 1.3 is tagged with "prod".  There have been 2 commits since version 1.3.

How can I pull a report to display index.html based on the "prod" tag?

There are times when files are committed but not tagged and we want to ensure we capture any changed files that need to move to production.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062584/cvs-list-all-files-added-removed-between-tags

Comment: @BurhanAli I've seen that question.  My situation is slightly different in that I don't have another tag to compare to.  Would I simply add a temporary tag to every file in the directory in order to catch the items changed since my "prod" tag?

Comment: If you omit the second tag it will use the newest revision of each file.

Comment: @BurhanAli Awesome.  This worked perfectly.cvs rdiff -s -r myTag myModule

Comment: @BurhanAli I have you credit on your other answer.  Thanks again.