# CVS - list files between tags

Tags: cvs

Guys is there any way to list only those cvs filenames that have changed between two tags?

Ideally I require a command that not only displays the filenames that have changed but also files that have been added and deleted.

Something like this but supercharged to include added and deleted files:

cvs -q log -NSR -rtag1::tag2 2>/dev/null >log.txt

Comment: possible duplicate of [CVS: list all files added/removed between tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062584/cvs-list-all-files-added-removed-between-tags)

Comment: It's similar but I'd ideally prefer not to have to specify particular module names (this could be a very large list) and for the unchanged files to not appear in the output.

Comment: That answer seems to be what you are after. It lists file names and whether they are new, changed or removed. rdiff options give you this summary format but diff options don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

cvs -q diff -N -r tag1 -r tag2 | grep "RCS file:" > log.txt

Files that have changed will be listed in log.txt with a 'v' next to their name. Added and deleted files are listed without this 'v'.

It would be nice to be able to distinguish between the added or deleted files but I've yet to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: This will only work if someone has added a `$RCSFile$` keyword to a file.

Comment: Alternatively use "Index:" > log.txt but you then won't get any indication in the output of whether the file was added, deleted or modified.